# Overlapping a DIV over 2 other DIVs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've some content in form of a bar like this:
[image]
But I need the edge (or end of bar) to be pointed. In order to do that I added another div with `white` borders. However, using this approach I am able to hide content of one div but other div's contents are still visible.
[image]
I tried to fix it using `z-index` but with no luck.

**Problem**:
[image]
[JS Fiddle setup](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitkandhal/jeyL3hqf/)

P.S.:

1. Can't use clip-path, shape-inside, shape-outside because of inconsistent browser support.
2. Third div's inside content would be transparent.

```css
.parent {
  left: 0.00%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
}
.child {
  width: 62%;
}
.row1 {
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: .25;
  background-color: blue;
}
.row2 {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.row3 {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  margin: -40px 0 0 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="row1">
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
    </div>
    <div class="row3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are your browser reqruiements?

Comment: depending on how hacky you want to do things you can create a div the same corner as the background, rotate it using css transforms and position it over the part you don't want visible....

Answer (score 3):

Just remove this line, which is not needed, because a block element occupies all available space:

```css
.row1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And then add some margin, in order to reduce the available space:

```css
.row1 {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  left: 0.00%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
}
.child {
  width: 62%;
}
.row1 {
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  opacity: .25;
  background-color: blue;
}
.row2 {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.row3 {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  margin: -40px 0 0 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="row1"></div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
    <div class="row3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent div a background that is an arrow set its position to top right then give it a right-padding that is equal to the background width. That should do it. No need for row3.

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of .row3, and use this CSS triangle jobby (assuming that the height of .child in your Fiddle is what it will be - easy to fix for other sizes though). Here's [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/t0evhcek/) of it.

```
.child:after {
content:"";
display:block;
position:absolute;
right:-20px;
top:0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a different approach, but would this be an option.

Create an arrow with the border property and float it against another div that functions as the bar.
Use CSS gradient as an option to color your bar.
Based on creating an arrow point with CSS from CSS tricks.com
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

**CSS**

```
  .arrow-right {
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        border-left: 40px solid blue;
        border-top: 40px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
        width:0;
        height:0;
    }
    .bar {
        width:300px;
        height:80px;
        background: blue;
        float:left;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="arrow-right">
```

fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/9btLx621/

With a two color bar using CSS gradient
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/9btLx621/2/

**EDIT**
Make the arrow seemingly part of a content div.

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #ddd;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
#content:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<!-- DIV CONTENT WITH ARROW -->
<div id="content">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel but my use case is a little bit different. 1. I need pointer to be part of the content, instead of extending it. 2. Content in my case is some textual content and cannot use `blue` color for border. I tried the CSS tricks and it's good. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Rohit - You're welcome. I stumbled myself on the CSS arrow and just happen to play with it. Your post adds a little challenge to that.  ...  With some adjustments it is possible to use the CSS arrow and apply it to a div that holds content. I played around some more for my own entertainment and got the above added result. Perhaps that might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this css style:

```
.row3 {
background-color: red;
float: right;
margin: -40px 0 0 337px;
border-top: 20px solid white;
border-bottom: 20px solid white;
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jeyL3hqf/4/